# Memcached Issue connection lost in between Centos

Tags: linux, nginx, load-balancing, memcached

I have a application server on with I m running load balance with nginx.. my memcached is getting crashed in between.

below is my `memcache.conf` file.

```
 # memcached.conf

port=11211
pidpath=/apps/home/memcached/bin/memcache_process.pid
user=root
maxconn=1024
cachesize=4096
options=20
logfile=/apps/home/memcached/logs/memcached.log
```

startup file

```
  #!/bin/bash
echo "Memcached is starting"
MPATH=`dirname "$0"`
cd $MPATH
. ../../conf/memcached.cnf
$MPATH/memcached -d -p $port -u $user  -m $cachesize -c $maxconn -P $pidpath -d $options -vv > $logfile 2>&1
```

below are the memcached log file

```
<584 version
584 VERSION 1.4.15
<617 new auto-negotiating client connection
614: Client using the ascii protocol
<614 version
614 VERSION 1.4.15
<616 new auto-negotiating client connection
<618 new auto-negotiating client connection
<619 new auto-negotiating client connection
<620 new auto-negotiating client connection
<621 new auto-negotiating client connection
<622 new auto-negotiating client connection
<626 new auto-negotiating client connection
<624 new auto-negotiating client connection
<628 new auto-negotiating client connection
<623 new auto-negotiating client connection
<627 new auto-negotiating client connection
<625 new auto-negotiating client connection
<629 new auto-negotiating client connection
<630 new auto-negotiating client connection
<631 new auto-negotiating client connection
631: Client using the ascii protocol
```

help me experts stuck on it since last 1 week, tried all things still not getting any thing..

Comment: But how do you confirm it has "crashed"?  Is it that the PID in `/apps/home/memcached/bin/memcache_process.pid` cannot be found with `ps`?  It is a strange place to keep a PID file by the way.

Comment: Config file name I written here is typo mistake, and it's crashing u can see again and again it's reconnecting

Comment: Fix your question please.

Comment: Please insert a new second line in your startup script containing `set -x`. Restart the server. [Add into your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/293797/edit) the line from this new debug that shows the `memcached` command and its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file is `memcache.conf` but your source statement in the startup file references `memcached.cnf`.